# How I sell or donate an old gas-powered fireplace insert?

Tags: fireplace

We have a number of gas-powered fireplaces in our house--one too many, as it turns out.

We've had the unit disconnected, and would like to get rid of it, preferably getting some money back as we do so. It's still built into a wall, but could probably be removed and reused by someone who wants a nice gas fireplace like that.

How would you go about doing this? Is there a service to call, or a marketplace for such things?

Comment: Where to sell things is considered localized and is off-topic. If you wanted to know how to remove it, that would be on-topic. But Craigslist of Kijiji come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the size and weight of fireplace inserts any market would have to be local in order to be economical.  Here in the SF Bay area we have a bunch of salvage yards where people pay truly outrageous prices for used junk.  Craigslist is also an option, and perhaps Habitat for Humanity would take it off your hands?  Just throwing ideas out there.